# FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId(); throw java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE in offline

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to unsubscribe from firebase push notification when user logout from application.

For it I use `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();`

It works when the device have internet connection. If the device does not have internet connection `"java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE" is occurred.`

How correct unsubscribe from push notification if device doesn't have internet connection ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic):

> To unsubscribe, the client app calls Firebase Cloud Messaging `unsubscribeFromTopic()` with the topic name.

If there is no internet connection, this will queue up the unsubscribe until the client is connected again.

Comment: Server send push notification to each user using device's registration token. So unsubscribeFromTopic() doesn't help me in this case.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you meant by unsubscribing in that case. How did the user subscribe to a push notification in the first place?

Comment: User generate device registration token and send it to server. Server uses it to send notifications.  And in case when user log out from application I don't want to receive notification for the user. So for it I use FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId() but it doesn't work in offline.

Comment: That is correct: there is no subscription in that case, so you need to suppress the notifications another way, e.g. by checking in code whether the user is signed in before showing a notification. This in turn might require that you only use data messages, so that they're always delivered to your code, instead of being handled by the system.